# I can be quite resourceful

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Take me whole, I can be quite resourceful
>   Remove one letter, I’m something you can pull
>   Remove once more, I can be present anytime
>   Remove once again, I won’t be here this time

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> CLEVER

which is quite resourceful.

Remove one letter, I’m something you can pull

> LEVER you can pull a lever.

Remove once more, I can be present anytime

> EVER meaning that you were, and you are, and you will be.

Remove once again, I won’t be here this time

> EVE the famous Eve who was one of the first human beings. Now, not here. This could also mean a period of time before an event, hence not the present.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> Crafty

Take me whole, I can be quite resourceful

> **Crafty** = adept in the use of subtlety and cunning

Remove one letter, I’m something you can pull

> **Craft** = a boat especially of small size, cf the example of [tow-boats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse-drawn_boat)

Remove once more, I can be present anytime

> **Raft** = bring or fasten together (a number of objects) side by side. Rafting ensures a constant connection.

Remove once again, I won’t be here this time

> **Aft** =  in the stern of a ship or the tail of an aircraft (also used as an abbreviation for afternoon, if we are looking specifically for the link with time).